# How can I play Company of Heroes without creating a Relic account

Tags: company-of-heroes

I got Company of Heroes from the Humble THQ Bundle and after downloading it on Steam I can't seem to play the game without having to create an account with Relic. As far as I understand it, the game has a singleplayer and the text on startup seems to indicate that the account is optional. But I can't find any option to play without creating that account.

Is there any way around this, or do I really have to create an account just to play the singleplayer?

Comment: play the multiplayer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might seem a bit too easy.
But no. They famously absolutely require a login.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a way...

Go to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Open the "hosts" file in notepad

Copy and paste "127.0.0.1 reliclive.quazal.net" (without quotes) at the bottom of that file

Save and run the game

Answer (score 0):

You could start the game without internet and block all internet traffic in and out from Company of Heroes.